# "We interact daily" or "we daily interact". Which is correct?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I'm writing a piece and twice people have "corrected" this phrase

> We interact daily with...

to

> We daily interact with...

Is this a real correction? It feels that the former is correct, while the latter is incorrect. Am I right, are they right, or are they both correct?

Comment: The first seems more natural to me. OTOH I would say "We frequently interact with..."

Comment: whoever is correcting you is wrong lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some adverbs can be located wherever they damn please, the first sentence feels more right.
With that being said, an Ngram search shows no results for the second sentence.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm British and I sometimes find US English placement of adverbs can be surprising.

Then there are trends and style. It's possible that the writer wants to emphasise the fact of what a wonderfully dynamic team she leads.  Arguably this could be achieved by "We interact on a daily basis...", however longer adverb expressions don't belong in this shiny, fascistic world of modern cut-throat business.

For me, this placing of the adjective is thus a bit awkward, but perhaps it's meant to be, in order to be (sick bucket at the ready)... "disruptive".

Comment: I was about to suggest the 'interact on a daily basis' in a comment. I think it might be the reason for the false correction.

Answer (score 0):

I find "We interact daily with them" more natural than "We daily interact with them", but "We interact with them daily" even more natural. And [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/adverb-placement-in-english-1211117) is a website that agrees with me:

> Adverb placement of adverbs of time usually occurs at the end of a sentence or clause. Adverbs of manner tell us 'when' something is done.
> Examples:
> Angie likes relaxing at home on weekends.
> Our meeting takes place at three o'clock.
> Frank is having a checkup tomorrow afternoon.